# Amazon EC2: These instances have Termination Protection and will not be terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have made a mistake and can't connect to my server via SSH. So want to terminate it but when I tried to terminate it, the Yes button is unreachable. (See image)

It gave this error:

> These instances have Termination Protection and will not be
> terminated. Use the Change Termination Protection option from the
> Instances screen Actions menu to allow termination of these instances.

Have you ever seen like this error?  How can I delete this server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to console right click on the instance and select "Change termination protection"

[image]

Then in next pop up click on "Yes Disable" and then you can terminate the instance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Termination Protection protects you from accidentally terminating an instance. It can be enabled or disabled on a per instance basis at anytime. It is likely it was enabled when the instance was launched. Before you can terminate the instance you must disable the instance's Termination Protection. As the message says, in the AWS console's EC2 instances view, select the instance, click the `Actions` menu, click `Instance Settings`, and then `Change Termination Protection`.